# Transfer mesh to another rig

Tags: rigging

I'm new to blender and I have a rigging/skinning question

Here's my scenario: I have two rigs (Rig A and Rig B) which are identical in every way. And I also have two meshes (Mesh A and Mesh B) where Mesh A is skinned to Rig A and Mesh B is skinned to Rig B.

I would like to make Mesh B skinned to Rig A rather than Rig B... I don't want to alter the weights at all, I just want to make it so that when I move the bones of Rig A, Mesh A and Mesh B both move accordingly

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Hey! welcome to blender stack exchange, correct me if I am wrong, so you have 2 individual rigged meshes and you wish to switch the rigs for either of them such that rig A although being in the mesh A but when moved, affects the movement of mesh B and same goes for the other rig. Is it the usecase you are talking about ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That’s kind of it, I’ll be more specific: I have two character rigs which are identical, the character meshes which belong to each rig are different. I would like to make it so that both meshes are skinned to the same skeleton so that I can export one rig (with both character meshes) to a game engine. Then, in the game engine I can toggle the meshes on/off to change the appearance of the character. 

So I guess what I’m asking is how can I transfer the bone weight information (probably the wrong terminology) to another rig with identical structure?